# Convergence of a series implies convergence of sequence

Tags: real-analysis

Firstly this is an assignment question. I was looking for some input as to whether I was working in the correct direction. Many thanks for any help!

Let $a_n \ge 0$ for all $n \ge 1$, and suppose that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ is convergent. Deduce the existence of a real number $N$ such that $a_n < 1$ for all $n \ge N$.

My thoughts are that since we are told the series $a_n$ is convergent, by the $n^{th}$ test the underlying sequence $a_n$ must tend to $0$.

So let $\epsilon > 0$, then there exists an $N$ such that $|a_n - 0 | < \epsilon$ for all $n \ge N$.

Then by defining $\epsilon = 1$, this should then deduce the existence of the real number $N$.

I'm fairly sure this is what I'm supposed to do but I just feel as though I may have missed something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't missed anything and are finding it difficult to evaluate your own proof only because you have overwritten it.:)  Your first statement, "the underlying sequence an must tend to 0" immediately implies the desired result.  For, since the sequence convergence to $0$, some "tail" of that sequence is contained in the 1-neghborhood of $0$ (i.e., in the interval $]-1, 1[$).  The index of the first term of that tail is your $N$.